# Weird abstract type construct in a method in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, refinement-type

browsing cats code, and found this

```
object ops {
    implicit def toAllInvariantOps[F[_], A](target: F[A])(implicit tc: Invariant[F]): AllOps[F, A] {
      type TypeClassType = Invariant[F]
    } =
      new AllOps[F, A] {
        type TypeClassType = Invariant[F]
        val self: F[A] = target
        val typeClassInstance: TypeClassType = tc
      }
  }
```

I do not under the `{type TypeClassType = Invariant[F]}` followed by `=`

If the function definition (parameter declaration) end with

```
implicit def toAllInvariantOps[F[_], A](target: F[A])(implicit tc: Invariant[F]): AllOps[F, A]
```

and the body is

```
=
      new AllOps[F, A] {
        type TypeClassType = Invariant[F]
        val self: F[A] = target
        val typeClassInstance: TypeClassType = tc
      }
```

What exactly is `{type TypeClassType = Invariant[F]}`

I mean from a syntax point of you i do not understand what it does in there ? Never seen a function written like that. Help ?

Comment: It's a type refinement. Does the answer linked answer your question?

Comment: Oh yeah, and you helped not long ago about this. Jeez, scala takes practice lol to recognize every bit of syntax :)

Thanks

Comment: With an alias, it was easier to see it ^^ !